# "in that way" - Which of the following three sentences is more correct to convey the desired meaning?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, word-order, adverbials, attachment-ambiguity

I'm **not** asking for a proof reading. And to further clarify, the Context is there to **only** provide context. I ask you to please ignore any perceived mistakes in the Context (located underneath the titular numbered sentences below).

> 1) Mary spoke with a smooth tone, and *in that way* finished her sentence.
>
> 2) Mary spoke with a smooth tone and *in that way*, she finished her sentence.
>
> 3) Mary spoke with a smooth tone and *in that way* finished her sentence.

Context:

Narrative first person character (Nar) is speaking to Mary.

> Nar: 
>   “……Are you okay with this? Even your life was on the line, wasn’t it?”
>
> Mary: 
>   “Because their purpose in keeping me alive is to kill people. Because it’s my time to die when I’m unable to kill.”
>
> Sentence (1) (2) or (3), based on which best fits the desired meaning below

I want the placement of "in that way" in the second clause to mean that the second-clause's topic focuses more on the speaker and less on the action she is doing. I understand that there are Grammar rules for writing correct sentences in English, which is why I'm searching for clarity on the nuances of the italicized phrase in *only* sentences (1) and (2); seeing as in (3) it's being used as a descriptive conjunction for the two clauses.

Edit: The context and numbered sentences are translated sentences. I currently lack the original text; due to my copy of the original file being on my home computer 2,000 miles away from me.

(Currently typing this edit on my phone; I apologize for any typos)

When I again have access to the above file, I’ll cross-reference the information gained here with what is on the original on my own (as posting the original here might be mistaken as requesting a proof-read; a translation-request; and other off-topic infractions).

Comment: Both sentences are very odd to a native speaker. Does 'in that way' refer to Mary's tone of voice? (_Fluent_ describes the ease with which a person brings out their words, not to a tone of voice.) If _she_ is Mary, why mention her twice in a short sentence?

Comment: In my opinion, sentence 2 is crafted better.